# FFTW: Undefined reference to fftw_mpi_init

Tags: mpi, fftw

I am using MPI to run FFTW but it triggers undefined reference error as below when compiling the program with `-lfftw3f_mpi -lfftw3f -lm`.

```
function main: error: undefined reference to 'fftw_mpi_init'
function main: error: undefined reference to 'fftw_destroy_plan'
```

But if modifying with `-lfftw3_mpi -lfftw3 -lm` that uses `double` type as default, it successfully gets compiled.

Does anyone know why?

Comment: Have you tried switching the order: `-lfftw3f -lfftw3_mpi`?

Comment: @MadPhysicist, if both libraries are provided as shared objects, the order does not matter. If they are static objects, `-lfftw3f_mpi -lfftw3f` is the correct one since `libfftw3f_mpi.a` refers code from `libfftwf.a` and not vice versa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the corresponding functions are called `fftwf_mpi_init` and `fftwf_destroy_plan`. Extract from the documentation that can be found [here](http://www.fftw.org/doc/Precision.html#Precision):

- Link to the single/long-double libraries; on Unix, `-lfftw3f` or `-lfftw3l` instead of (or in addition to) `-lfftw3`. (You can link to the different-precision libraries simultaneously.)
- Include the same `<fftw3.h>` header file.
- Replace all lowercase instances of `fftw_` with `fftwf_` or `fftwl_` for single or long-double precision, respectively. (`fftw_complex` becomes `fftwf_complex`, `fftw_execute` becomes `fftwf_execute`, etcetera.)
- Uppercase names, i.e. names beginning with `FFTW_`, remain the same.
- Replace `double` with `float` or `long double` for subroutine parameters.